# AngularJS two way binding with multiple select options

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a list of fields that are not exclusive. Typically you would use html check boxes and bind each one to a Boolean value in the model. However I have been thrown a curve, to save space the users want all of the items to be presented in a select that allows multiple selections. I know how to create the select itself in HTML however I am not sure the best way to wire that up the model using the 'Angular way'. Is there a better solution than creating something in the controller to "translate" the select result to series of Booleans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS. Bootstrap multiselect without JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799228/angularjs-bootstrap-multiselect-without-jquery)

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Try using this directive:
https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect

More info on SO here: [AngularJS. Bootstrap multiselect without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799228/angularjs-bootstrap-multiselect-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a var in scope for the dropdown. Which wasn't too big of a deal as I keep my view model in a var called viewmodel, so it will not post to the server with rest of the view model. Then in my load and save functions I 'boxed' and 'unboxed' the booleans into a string array I fed to and read from the dropdown. little bit of work but it works. I was hoping the AngularJS framework could have handled this lifting for me but whatev.

Too bad you cannot data bind to an option in the select list (selected == true).